# Cannot configure Qt 4.8 rc

Tags: qt, qt4

I've downloaded Qt 4.8 rc and installed it. There is no Qt Creator included there so I wanted to add Qt 4.8 to Qt Creator's Qt's versions but when I've pointed out to qt4.8/bin/qmake I'm getting info from Qt Creator that Qt isn't properly installed, please run make install.
So I did it (this is from console):

```
Setting up a MinGW/Qt only environment...  
-- QTDIR set to C:\Qt\4.8.0  
-- PATH set to C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin  
-- Adding C:\MinGW32\bin to PATH  
-- Adding C:\WINDOWS\System32 to PATH  
-- QMAKESPEC set to win32-g++  

C:\Qt\4.8.0>make install
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for `install'.  

C:\Qt\4.8.0>
```

Does anyone knows what am I suppose to do?
Edit:

```
Setting up a MinGW/Qt only environment...
-- QTDIR set to C:\Qt\4.8.0
-- PATH set to C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin
-- Adding C:\MinGW32\bin to PATH
-- Adding C:\WINDOWS\System32 to PATH
-- QMAKESPEC set to win32-g++

C:\Qt\4.8.0>make install
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for `install'.

**C:\Qt\4.8.0>make -B install
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for `install'.
C:\Qt\4.8.0>**
```

Answer (score 0):

`make install` may have annotated somehow that it has actually done the install once already. If you want to force it, try `make -B install`:

```
   -B, --always-make
        Unconditionally make all targets.
```

Comment: What about a `make` between `configure` and `make install`?

Comment: @Lars: worth a short -- I assumed the "and installed it" meant that it had been compiled too and perhaps one of the install steps had been missed.

Answer (score 0):

must do this order

configure

make

make install